# Additional unused pages for partitions after migration from SQL server 2012 to SQL server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2019

After migrating from SQL server 2012 to SQL server 2019 one of the tables and only one on which we have partitions is using more space. From what i noticed SQL Server is reserving more pages for each partitions but is not using them. Is there any reason for this behaviour that was added in SQL Server versions after 2012r2?
To be more precise i checked `sys.allocations_units` and partitions created on 2012r2 and moved to 2019 have `total_pages` at 5.1M and `used_pages` also at 5.1M difference is 1000 pages and partitions created after migration have `total_pages` at 15M while `used_pages` are still at 5M

Comment: There is not enough information to help answer. Please make, at a minimum, a valid repro.

Comment: @SeanGallardy-MostlyRetired figured it out trace flag 692 was required.